# Avoid class initialization modified in method in python

Tags: python, class, initialization

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np

class xx():
   def __init__(self, x):
      self.x = x
   def main(self):
      for i in [0,1,2,3]:
         y = self.x
         y[0, i] = 0
         print(y)
z = np.array([[0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8],[1,2,3,4],[6,4,3,1]])        
xx(z).main()
```

My original code is far more complicated than this, so I decided to create a similar example on the issue.

I meant to only change y in the for loop, and reassign y with self.x. but it seemed that self.x was changed in the for loop too. How can I avoid self.x getting modified each time as y changes?

Comment: Could not recreate, I get your desired output as expected. Strings are *immutable*, and you don't explictly update `self.x`, so each assignment `y = self.x` gets the value `'David'`.

Comment: well it seems your current code currently gives me the desired output. you may need to clarigy more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `copy.deepcopy()`

```
import copy

class xx():
   def __init__(self, x):
      self.x = x
   def main(self):
      for i in [0,1,2]:
         y = copy.deepcopy(self.x)
         y[0, i] = 0
         print(y)
z = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])
xx(z).main()

>>>[[0 1 1]
    [2 2 2]]

>>>[[1 0 1]
    [2 2 2]]

>>>[[1 1 0]
    [2 2 2]]
```

Comment: In my original code, it's numpy array. So python does not distinguish two objects such as dataframe numpy when reassigning? The variables are pointing to the same object using '='?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but notice that when you wrote the line `y = self.x` and then `y[0, i] = 0` those two lines are equivalent to `self.x[0, i] = 0` , since the `y` variable is just a pointer to self.x, when you use `copy.deepcopy()` you create a new object in the memory and can modify it without overwriting `self.x`